# Insert dynamic controls into middle of controls collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, dynamic-controls

this is my very first post! I'm pretty desperate so I'm going above and beyond my standard googling. I believe this is an advanced or expert-level .NET question.

The problem is that I have built a .NET web application that needs to be able to insert user controls dynamically into the middle of a list. I'm quite comfortable with dynamic controls so long they only need to be added to the end of the list (ie: I'm familiar with articles like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). However, if I need to add a UserControl to the front of a Controls collection or somewhere in the middle I'm pretty much lost since the UniqueID of the control is thrown off.

As a simplified example, let's say that i have a Panel to which I am adding a list of UserControls called MyControl.ascx. I also have some event that can get fired on the page to that needs to dynamically insert a MyControl.ascx into the specified index of the Controls collection of the panel. I also have one or more events on MyControl.ascx to which I need to subscribe. This means that the controls need to be loaded BEFORE the events on these controls would fire or else they will not fire. If you don't know to what I'm referring then I either worded the question poorly or this question might be too difficult for you :)

Below is some C# pseudocode to demonstrate the issue. The problem is that the Controls.AddAt(index, control) method does NOT adjust the UniqueID values of the controls accordingly. For example, consider the following controls in a Controls collection:

Whether I'm actually writing code that directly depends on the UniqueID or not, .NET indirectly uses the UniqueID to link together the events that were fired on the previous postback with the controls get loaded on the new postback. Taking my previous example of:

On initial `Page Load (Page.IsPostback == false)`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width='100'>Control index</td>
    <td width='75'>UniqueID</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>ctl00</td>
    <td>value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ctl01</td>
    <td>value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>ctl02</td>
    <td>value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After a postback (`Page.IsPostback == false`) from some other control that wants to insert the control at index 0:

If i do a `Controls.AddAt(0, newControl)` then the Controls collection looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width='100'>Control index</td>
    <td width='75'>UniqueID</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>ctl03</td>
    <td>value0  <== the controls' unique IDs do not shift!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ctl00</td>
    <td>value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>ctl01</td>
    <td>value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>ctl02</td>
    <td>value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if i were to click on a linkbutton in the control with Value == value0 and UniqueID == ctl03, the controls would be ordered like the following on post-back and the UniqueIDs would not be in the order i want. This will cause the click event to attach to the wrong control:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width='100'>Control index</td>
    <td width='75'>UniqueID</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>ctl00</td>
    <td>value0  <== the control i wanted to throw the event</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ctl01</td>
    <td>value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>ctl02</td>
    <td>value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>ctl03</td>
    <td>value3  <== the actual control to which the event is attached</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If i didn't have to handle events from these dynamic controls this probably wouldn't be a problem. Here is my code:

```
// on init i just need to pull the records from the DB, turn them
// into a MyControl.ascx, and then add them to my panel
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    // get my List<SomethingFromDB> ordered by value and iterate through, 
    // adding controls to the control collection
    List<SomethingFromDB> myList = remoteService.GetSomeListFromTheDB();
    foreach(SomethingFromDB something in List<SomethingFromDB>)
    {
        // load a new MyControl.ascx
        MyControl myControl = (MyControl )LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl .ascx");
        // populate the values of myControl with the "something"
        this.populateMyControl(something);
        // dynamically add the control to my panel
        this.myPanel.Add(myControl);     
        // subscribe to event
        myControl.SomeArbitraryEvent += new EventHandler(MyArbitraryHandler);
    }

    // This event gets fired by a magical control on the page and passes a 
    // new SomethingFromDB which needs to be inserted into the DB and then 
    // dynamically inserted into the Controls collection at the specified index
    private void SomeOtherControl_ClickInsert(object sender, MyControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // insert this record into the DB             
        remoteService.InsertIntoDB(e.SomethingFromDB);     
        // dynamically load this control
        MyControl myControl = (MyControl )LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl .ascx");
        // get the index into which we will be inserting this control
        int index = e.NewIndex;                   
        //dynamically add the control to my panel at the specified index.
        // THIS DOES NOT ADJUST THE UNIQUEID VALUES ACCORDINGLY
        // AND IS THE SOURCE OF MY PROBLEM!
        this.myPanel.AddAt(index, myControl);
    }
```

Please help. This one is killing me. If you need more information or have questions please let me know and I'd be happy to provide more info. I GREATLY appreciate your help!

Comment: See now, you're going about this the wrong way, you're explaining your problem rather than explaining what you want to accomplish. There's a difference in that which makes it hard to suggest better ways (which sometimes are the right ways) of going about a particular problem. Edit your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make automatic numbering work, you want the controls to be added to the panel in the same order for every postback. Obviously, on a postback, the controls have to have their unique IDs assigned, or you wouldn't get the control event.

`UniqueID` is initialised on first use to the value of the `Control.ID`* property. If that property is not set, it is automatically generated as `ctlxx`, as you have observed. Once assigned, a control's `UniqueID` is read-only.

Therefore, if you have some form of primary key, you can set the `ID` property of the control when you create it based on that primary key. The `UniqueID` will then be set to that value when the page loads its state.

- Footnote: the `UniqueID` property is actually a combination of the naming container's prefix and the `ID`  property.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sunlight. The UniqueID gets set as soon as I add it to myPanel. The problem is that by the time the "SomeOtherControl_ClickInsert" is called, the controls are already on the panel have and a UniqueID assigned. When i go to insert my conrol it is already too late.

Comment: I really hate this 300 character limit.

Anyway, I am aware that the UniqueID is a combination of the parent control(s) and page as well as the index of the control in the controls collection. I just don't see how I can put a control in the middle of the collection and hook to the right event

Comment: ... hook to the right event on postback if one of the dynamic controls is clicked. Could you elaborate a little more? I may have worded my question poorly, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh wait... i see what you are saying now! I haven't yet set my control.ID when I add it to the panel--that is why it is setting a uniqueID of its own. Since i do in fact have a primary key value I should be able to set the ID to that key. I'll play around with it and post back soon. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, you are officially a genius. That was exactly the problem! I wasn't setting my control.ID BEFORE adding it to another control collection so .NET was taking the liberty of using their own counter. When i assign the ID to my own primary key value the problem is solved. Thanks Sunlight!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following attribute in the page directive.

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true
```

This helps out, I believe.